# Embed Twitter feed into website but display in carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, carousel

We are currently embedding Twitter feeds across our websites using the embedded Twitter widget - https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/embed-twitter-feed

As far as I can see, the tweets can only be displayed one on top of the other

Is there a way to embed using the widget and display using a Bootstrap carousel format?

I did investigate using the Twitter API to retrieve the data and build my own carousel but the rate limit of the API (720 requests per hour) versus costs means it is a non-starter